# Relationship between multiple JOINs

Tags: mysql, join

If I have a sequence of multiple JOINs in a MySQL query, such as

```
1. SELECT * FROM x 
2.    LEFT JOIN y ON x.id = y.id; 
3.    LEFT JOIN z ON x.id z.id 
4. ...
```

Is each individual left join applied to what results from SELECT in line 1, or is the query processed in such a way that the first left join is applied to the results of SELECT and the second left join to the results of the preceding left join? Thanks

Comment: I had the same question and believe a valid and interesting one and it does have a lot sense unlike other's responses :). Multiple joins works like a single join in a sequential manner. There is a dependency as explained in the following [Ref](https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/multiple-joins-work-just-like-single-joins/)

Answer (score 1):

Your `JOIN` rule is declared *exactly* by your `ON` clause. I.e. your question have no sense - you have a clear declaration that you're joining table `x` with `y` and table `x` with `z`. If you query would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM x 
LEFT JOIN y ON x.id = y.id
LEFT JOIN z ON y.id z.id
```

then it will be `x -> y -> z` join - see that it is declared in `ON y.id = z.id`. Your current query represent `z <- x -> y` join.

You can see description of `SQL JOIN` [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).